# Including multiple Databases in DB2 Debezium kafka source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, db2, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, connector

Does DB2 Debezium source connector supports connecting to multiple Databases in single connector. The mysql Debezium connector provides the property database.include.list where I can supply multiple databases separated by comma. However there is no such property provided by DB2 Debezium connector. In DB2 Dabezium connector the database is provided using the property database.dbname. However when I am passing mutiple databases name as comma separated then I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't obtain database name
```

Is there a way to supply multiple db names to Debezium DB2 connectore?